# How to intercept HTTP request before passing to any web server like APACHE or NGINX?

Tags: apache-httpd, nginx, webserver

I would like to send a custom response before any request hit to any web server like APACHE, NGINX or any other.

I heard about `Content-filtering` and  `Packet-filtering`. So I am not looking for the filtering process.

Actually I am looking for intercepting request and sending a custom response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for an [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). Specifically, [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org) has a Python API that can be used to automatically send a custom response programmatically, (See: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-scripting).